# Highcharts remove column defined by keys from export to CSV

Tags: csv, highcharts, export

I am controlling the `marker.enabled` of each point in my data set using `series.keys` -  something like `keys: ['x','y','marker.enabled']` and data looks like `[[1609459200,10,false], [1609459200,20,true]...]`

The problem is - when exporting to CSV - instead of getting just the Y data as a column I'm now getting all 3 keys as columns - `title(x), title(y), title(marker.enabled)`

I know I can change the `data` from array of arrays to array of objects, get rid of `keys` and achieve the same - but I still wonder if there is an option to keep the keys yet only export the Y as if keys is `undefined`

I tried overriding `keys` to undefined in `exporting.chartOptions` but it doesn't seem to affect CSV.

Any easy way to do it?
Thanks.

EDIT:
a jsfiddle with a sample https://jsfiddle.net/3f4a1xdo/
Although it does not really export - the table shows how it would look like when exporting as CSV. notice how `keys` causes the table to include `Temperature(x)` which is a duplicate of `Day` and `Temperature(Y)`. If you comment out the `keys` line the table shows nicely without touching the actual data.

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue on some online editor with the sample data?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel added

Comment: Is this an output that you want to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/thLdm5er/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel thanks for trying to help! almost - your fiddle still has the (y) key attached to the value column (thus also the title shows as multiple lines). I just want the column to have the series name - just Temperature, as if keys wasn't used at all

Comment: Setting the `exporting.useMultiLevelHeaders` gives the wanted output - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9b2vezc7/ let me know if it is a correct answer to your question - if so I will add it as an official answer

Comment: @SebastianWędzel not exactly because the title of the column still has the (y) from the key

Comment: You can edit the headers by using the `columnHeaderFormatter` callback. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.csv.columnHeaderFormatter Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5zthymxg/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel this seems to do what I want - ignore the keys eventually. Thanks :)

Comment: @SebastianWędzel please note that if there are multiple series to export - the extra key(s) columns need to be removed from each series - so I had to do something like
```e.dataRows.forEach(function(el) {
            for (var i = 1; i < el.length; i += 1) {
                el.splice(i, 1); //remove the seriesn_x
                el.splice(i+1, 1); //remove the seriesn_undefined (marker.enabled) element
            }
        });```

Comment: @SebastianWędzel another 2 questions: 1) when using array of 3-element arrays defined by keys, even when array.length > turboThreshold I don't get error #12 which contradicts the documentation of only allowing 1 or 2 dimensional arrays. 2) for performance - is array of arrays faster/better than array of objects or vice versa with ~10k data points?

Comment: 1) The reproduction of this issue could be very useful, without it it's hard to say. 2) it doesn't matter, but you should consider using the boost module to improve performance - https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module

Comment: @SebastianWędzel you can post your suggested solution as an answer and I will accept it. Otherwise I can post it myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments - there is a final solution for this issue:

To remove one column:

```
H.addEvent(H.Chart, 'exportData', function(e) {
  e.dataRows.forEach(function(el) {
    el.splice(1, 1);
  });
});
```

To edit table headers:

```
csv: {
  columnHeaderFormatter: function(item, key) {
    if (item.isXAxis) {
      return 'Category'
    } else {
      return item.name
    }
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5zthymxg/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.csv.columnHeaderFormatter

Comment: You could return false if `item.isXAxis` to use the default header name by Highchart which may be "DateTime"